# rails 3.1 scaffold generator broke for project, just stopped working: no such file to load -- rails_generator (LoadError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, scaffolding

SOLVED, see comment below, discovered 'enumerated_attribute' gem breaks rails scaffold

My rails 3.1 scaffolding just broke for my project. (scaffolding still works fine in my other 3.0 and 3.1 projects-- only one project has a broken scaffold generator!)

In my rail 3.1 project, I have scaffolded multiple models the past few days, then today out of the blue `rails g scaffold Mymodel` is failing with the error message:

> /Users/johndoe/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in
>   `require': no such file to load -- rails_generator (LoadError)

I didn't switch rails versions mid-way or anything, the project has always been rails 3.1.3, and it's been working fine until I tried it again today for a new model.

Does anyone have any idea how to fix it and/or what might have caused it to suddenly break?

(rails g migration works fine... it's just scaffolding that is broken!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved. Here is the fix:

1. Comment out `enumerated_attribute` gem in the Gemfile
2. Do scaffolding
3. Replace `enumerated_attribute` gem in  the Gemfile.

Answer (score 0):

Just removing enumerated_attribute did not work for me. I then got errors complaining about undefined method 'enum_attr' (as you would expect), meaning I need to also comment out every attr of my models using enum_attr. I used the following gem version:

```
gem 'enumerated_attribute', :git => 'git://github.com/jeffp/enumerated_attribute.git'
```

This fixed the issue for me.

Comment: I've been reluctant to update the gem, a little concerned it might break something else. The key to my workaround is that you comment out the gem ONLY long enough to run the generator. You never run your app with it commented out. Eg (1) comment out in Gemfile (2) run generator (3) replace gem in Gemfile.

Comment: That is what I did. I tried running the generator after commenting out in the Gemfile and was getting an error on one of my Concerns that contiains an enumeration. I didn't try running the app because I couldn't get the generator to run. The best workaround I could find is to replace the gem 'enumerated_attribute' with the git version only long enough to run the generator. Once the generator succeeds, I revert back to gem 'enumerated_attribute' again.